# How do I make a BasicAuth REST query over SSL with python3

Tags: python-3.x, afnetworking, urllib

I have a tornado server that acts as a REST interface to an iPhone app. I want to do some queries against said server using a python program. On the iOS side, I'm using the `AFNetworking` library. But I don't know what the analogs are on the python client side.

My ObjectiveC/AFNetworking code looks something like:

```
+ (HttpConnection*) current {
    static HttpConnection* current = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        current = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL: [NSURL URLWithString: BaseURL]];
        current.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
        current.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        current.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    });
    [current.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername: Username password: Password];
    return current;
}

- (void)pull: (NSString*)resource fields: (NSArray*)fields then: (void(^)())block {
    //  NSLog(@"%@ pulling...", self);
    NSString* uri = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", [self rootREST], self.serialID];
    if (resource) {
        uri = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", uri, resource];
    }
    [[HttpConnection current]
        GET: uri
        parameters: fields ? @{@"fields": fields} : nil
        success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, id responseObject){
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(fromDoc:) withObject:responseObject waitUntilDone:YES];
            if (block) block();
        }
        failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, NSError* error){
            NSLog(@"%@ pull error: %@ (uri=%@)", self, error, uri);
        }
    ];
}
```

So the features I'm looking for are:

1. Initialize with a BaseURL like `https://a.b.c:7895/`
2. Add the `resource/path`
3. Allow invalid (self signed) cert
4. Set `BasicAuth` header
5. Add additional parameters to the query
6. Run the GET request

Do I use `urllib` to do all of this? Or do I need to use something different. I would love an example of how I might do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend the python requests library (which I did check and it does support python 3.x).  It should be as simple as:

```
import requests
username = "SomeUser"
password = "SomePass"
r = requests.get("https://a.b.c:7895/resource/path?param1=foo",auth=(username,password),verify=False)
```

Comment: Looks like there's even a debian package for it. I'll give that a go, thanks.